# copy data based on criteria to another sheet and clear the contents

Tags: excel, vba

This code is working to copy the filtered data of "Award" column marked "Yes" to another sheet; however, I'm receiving an error of "Type Mismatch." I'm not 100% now that the code is working properly to filter the data and copy correctly. I currently have 23 rows of test data for proper functionality. If I only put one row of data, then it doesn't copy and paste the data correctly. I am left with the copied 1st row of data plus the 2nd empty row of data. Additionally, it is not clearing the contents of the rows after the paste, so I may add new data as the days progress.

```css
Sub CopySheet()
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim Search As String
Dim Column As Integer

Sheets("MasterData").Activate
Sheets("MasterData").Range("A1").Select
'Sets an Autofilter to sort out only your Yes rows.
Selection.AutoFilter
'Change Field:=5 to the number of the column with your Y/N.
Sheets("MasterData").Range("$A$1:$G$200000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Yes"

'Finds the last row
LastRow = Sheets("MasterData").Cells(Sheets("MasterData").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

i = 1
'Change the 3 to the number of columns you got in Sheet2
Do While i <= 11
    Search = Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Cells(1, i).Value
    Sheets("MasterData").Activate
    'Update the Range to cover all your Columns in MasterData.
    If IsError(Application.Match(Search, Sheets("MasterData").Range("A1:G1"), 0)) Then
        'nothing
    Else
        Column = Application.Match(Search, Sheets("MasterData").Range("A1:G1"), 0)
        Sheets("MasterData").Cells(2, Column).Resize(LastRow, 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Activate
        Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Cells(2, i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

'Clear all Y/N = Y
'Update the Range to cover all your Columns in MasterData.
Sheets("MasterData").Activate
Column = Application.Match("Award", Sheets("MasterData").Range("A1:F1"), 0)
Sheets("MasterData").Cells(2, Column).Resize(LastRow, 1).Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: what line of code is throwing the error? Also, if you're trying to only copy from the filtered data, you need to make sure you use Range().SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: It's not identifying the line of error when I run the code. The data is copying from only the filtered data, but if it's only one row, it doesn't copy just the one row.

Comment: Where would I throw that `Range().SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`?

Comment: I tried to put that code into the lines with `.Range`, but I'm now getting an error "Object not found"

Comment: Sorry I haven't offered you more help. Can you show/explain your data setup and what you're trying to do? You said: This code is working to copy the filtered data of "Award" column marked "Yes" to another sheet; however, I'm receiving an error of "Type Mismatch." If that's what you're trying to do, there's a much easier way.

Comment: Column headers `Job         Builder          Neighborhood    Lot# Address City Award`

Comment: data: `2015 BullardHomes Sample2 22 2222 Main St Fakeville No`

Comment: I see. Do you have to filter the data or did you think it would be easier to find the awards if it was filtered? I would skip the filtering all together and use the code I posted.

Comment: So if the Award is marked yes, I need those rows to be added to the ActiveJobStatus worksheet to the next empty row to keep all records. However, now the data won't be added if existing data is present.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to filter based on my lack of knowledge with extensive macros. I usually code clear contents or copy and pasting and that's it for simple data. I'm just not sure where to add the code you mentioned before, so I can run a test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to change your code up so much, but it looks like you might be over-complicating how to do it.

This is some code from a previous question I answered where someone wanted to highlight a specific range whenever the word "Total" was found.

I changed the find to "Yes". Change the SearchRange to your column. (I think G is right).

Also, for future reference, Select should [*almost never*] be used.

It slows down code execution quite a bit and is not required.

I know the macro recorder likes to use it, but everything can be referenced without using select.

Brief example:

```
Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Activate
Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Cells(2, i).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Can Be replaced by:

```
Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Cells(2, i).Paste
```

> This code is working to copy the filtered data of "Award" column marked "Yes" to another sheet.

```
Sub CopyAwardsToActiveJobStatusSheet()

Dim SearchRange, First, Finder As Range
Dim PasteRow as Integer 'Add this to increment the rows we paste your data to

Set SearchRange = Sheets("MasterData").Range("G:G") 'Search This Range for "Yes"

Set Finder = SearchRange.Find("Yes") 'This is what we're looking for
If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'We didn't find any "Yes" so we're done

'Drastically increases speed of every macro ever
'(well, when the sheets are modified at least - and it doesn't hurt)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

First = Finder.Address 'Grab the address of the first "Yes" so we know when to stop

'Get the last row of column "A" on ActiveJobStatusSheet and start pasting below it
PasteRow = Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Cells(Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Do
    'Copy the entire row and paste it into the ActiveJobStatus sheet
    'Column A and PasteRow (the next empty row on the sheet)
    'You can change these if needed
    Finder.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Range("A" & PasteRow)

    'If you just want A:G, you can use this instead:
    'Finder returns the cell that contains "Yes",
    'So we offset/resize to get the 6 cells before it and just copy that
    'Resize doesn't like negative numbers so we have to combine:

    'Finder.Offset(,-6).Resize(,7).Copy Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Range("A" & PasteRow)

    'Look for the next "Yes" after the one we just found
    Set Finder = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=Finder)

    PasteRow = PasteRow + 1 'Faster than looking for the end again

'Do this until we are back to the first address
Loop While Not Finder Is Nothing And Finder.Address <> First

'Clear MasterData
Sheets("MasterData").Range("A2:G" & Sheets("MasterData").UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Drastically increases speed of every macro ever.
End Sub
```

**Just the code:**

```
Sub CopyAwardsToActiveJobStatusSheet()
Dim SearchRange, First, Finder As Range
Dim PasteRow as Integer
Set SearchRange = Sheets("MasterData").Range("G:G")
Set Finder = SearchRange.Find("Yes")
If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
First = Finder.Address
PasteRow = Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Cells(Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Do
    Finder.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Range("A" & PasteRow)
    Set Finder = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=Finder)
    PasteRow = PasteRow + 1
Loop While Not Finder Is Nothing And Finder.Address <> First
Sheets("MasterData").Range("A2:G" & Sheets("MasterData").UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Results:**

MasterData Sheet:

[image: BeforeJob]

ActiveJobStatus Sheet:

[image: AfterJob]

Comment: Awesome, I'll check this out when I'm back in the office tomorrow morning. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to help you out - I was on my phone when I first commented. Basically, we get the last row of ActiveJobStatus (column A, you can change it to whatever) and that's where we paste the "Yes" awards we find (we paste the EntireRow - change "E:E" to whatever column "Award" is).

Comment: I tried to comment it so you understand what it's doing - hope this helps, i'll be around tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. This is much faster and the screen doesn't flash when I run the macro. Great job.

Comment: Glad to hear it, happy to help.

Comment: I had a second thought instead of clearing the contents after the paste. I would like to change the value of "Yes" to "Copied" upon completion. I'm taking a stab at this since the macro recorder isn't helping to replace the value.
`If Target.Column = "Copied" Then`
`For each cel in Range ("G:G")`
`If value = "Yes" Then`
`FormulaR1C1 = "Copied"`

Comment: Not sure why this didn't show up as a comment in my inbox. Since you're already finding the Yes values, just add finder.value = "Copied" after the line 
Finder.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ActiveJobStatus").Range("A" & PasteRow) - assuming you mean to change it on the original sheet. Of course, remove Sheets("MasterData").Range("A2:G" & Sheets("MasterData").UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents if you don't want it cleared